What is the difference between the nouns "truco" and "engaño"?
I have been taught both that el truco y el engaño are words that mean "trick", but no one has ever explained to me the difference. What tends to be the difference in these words, and does it matter when you use one over the other?

My dictionary claims that "engaño" is a masculine noun meaning "deceit". It can mean 'trick' in specific contexts. "truco" is a masculine noun literally meaning trick. My dictionary is Barron's Spanish-English.

Please check and post definitions from a dictionary, like the RAE. The words are unrelated.

It depends on the context but we could say that "truco" is something that a magician could do to trick you while "engaño" is more related to a scam.
Generally speaking "engaño" is more used on a negative context.
The Spanish Royal Academy (RAE from Spanish acronym) explanation for "engaño".


m. Falta de verdad en lo que se dice, hace, cree, piensa o discurre.



En español se usan en contextos distintos. Intentaré usar ejemplos a ver si te ayudo en algo.

Truco (Trick) = The magic trick was amazing = El truco de magia fue increíble

En este contexto, el Truco es el "método" usado para generar el Engaño (pero un engaño bueno o sano). Un truco de magia "engaña" tu vista.
Así mismo, el Engaño se podría traducir como Deception o Fraud. Pero esta palabra es más profunda.

Engaño (Deception/Fraud) = That man's deception/fraud was horrible = El Engaño/fraude de ese hombre fue horrible

Otro contexto

Usó un viejo truco para engañar a la dama = He used an old trick to fool the lady

